# Location of `validates` error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I recently ran into the issue where I was attempting to execute `rake db:seed` and had it failed.  After a fair amont of time of searching looking through logs and trying to determine the cause of the issue I realized that I had bad seed datat which was being rejected by my model in the following validation:

```
validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {¬
   with:    %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i,¬
   message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'¬
}¬
```

I was only able to identify that this by copy and pasting the my seed data and attempting to input it through the according view, where I received the error message `must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.`.

Where are `validates` error messages sent when `rake db:seed` is executed?

Answer (score 1):

Your are looking for the error messages:

```
# Create a new object
@model = Model.new(attributes)

# Validate it
@model.valid?

# Or save it (this calls #valid?)
@model.save

# Put error messages.
@model.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
  puts message
end
```

For your reference: http://ariejan.net/2010/12/15/why-did-errormessagesfor-disappear-from-rails-3

Comment: How are the error messages being outputted to the view without this?  I would rather not have to include this every time I create a model, is there a way to simply have all `validates` error messages outputted to the developer log?